# How to import highchart-more into angular 4 project

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts

In my angular 4 project I'm using highcharts for a combination chart of line column and a area range chart.

I'm using the following npm package for highcharts.
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts

here is how I imported the highcharts module in the typescript component

```
import { chart } from 'highcharts';
```

But my chart is dependent on highcharts-more.js file. this file is present in 
node-modules > highcharts folder.

whenever I'm using the area range chart i'm gettin error #17 which is because highcharts-more file missing.

How to import this highcharts-more module in to my component.

I tried `require('highcharts-more')` but it is of no use. Because I'm getting error with require as well.

Answer (score 3):

Check this gist: https://gist.github.com/jon-a-nygaard/f22ade93209277eea5b57c0f6ca51ea7

This should work:

```
import Highcharts from 'highcharts'
import addMore from "highcharts/highcharts-more";

addMore(Highcharts)
```

Gist taken from from github issue: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5638

**Alternative solution:**

```
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts'
import * as HighchartsMore from 'highcharts/highcharts-more.src.js'
HighchartsMore(Highcharts)
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error /@types/highcharts/highcharts-more"' has no default export.

Comment: Could you add your config to the question? Do you use webpack, typescript?  This may be the problem `import { chart } from 'highcharts';` (my answer has different import for Highcharts, it exports whole library).

Comment: I'm trying to use the gauge type chart which throws the same 17# error. I got the same 'has no default export' error and changed it to `import Highcharts = require('highcharts');` and `import addMore  = require( "highcharts/highcharts-more");` but the same error 17# occurred... any help?

Comment: Check the compiled javascript output - is highcharts lib included there? Have you installed typings for Highcharts from npm? Which version of Highcharts you have installed? Check this gist: https://gist.github.com/jon-a-nygaard/7b9b8c164325f564a2e6464acf4271be See also my edit (alternative solution).

Answer (score 0):

You could just use an Angular wrapper for Highchart, such as

`https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-highcharts`

Or if you are using Angular v4.0 then use

```
https://github.com/cebor/angular-highcharts/blob/4/README.md
```

Same repo, but the instructions are for Angular v4

Comment: no support for chart types that can be generated only when the highcharts-more file is added.